# How to access DOM elements in electron?

Tags: javascript, dom, electron

I am trying to add functionality to a button in `index.html` file is as follows:
I have a button element in `index.html`

```
<button id="auth-button">Authorize</button>
```

In `main.js` of the app, I have

```
require('crash-reporter').start();
console.log("oh yaeh!");
var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function(){
    if(process.platform != 'darwin'){
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('ready',function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:800, height : 600});
    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

    var authButton = document.getElementById("auth-button");
    authButton.addEventListener("click",function(){alert("clicked!");});

    mainWindow.openDevTools();

    mainWindow.on('closed',function(){
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

But an error occurs as follows:
`Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Can the DOM objects be accessed while building electron apps? or is there any other alternative way that can give me the required functionality?

Comment: The main process doesn't have access to the DOM, it's the renderer that has access. [Learn the difference](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md#differences-between-main-process-and-renderer-process)

Comment: Can you paste your index.html here

Answer (score 95, accepted):

DOM can *not* be accessed in the main process, only in the renderer that it belongs to.

There is an `ipc` module, available on [main process](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.8/api/ipc-main/) as well as the [renderer process](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.8/api/ipc-renderer/) that allows the communication between these two via sync/async messages.

You also can use the [remote](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.8/api/remote/) module to call main process API from the renderer, but there's nothing that would allow you to do it the other way around.

If you need to run something in the main process as a response to user action, use the `ipc` module to invoke the function, then you can return a result to the renderer, also using `ipc`.

*Code updated to reflect actual (v0.37.8) API, as @Wolfgang suggested in comment, see edit history for deprecated API, if you are stuck with older version of Electron.*

Example script in `index.html`:

```
var ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
authButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ipc.once('actionReply', function(event, response){
        processResponse(response);
    })
    ipc.send('invokeAction', 'someData');
});
```

And in the main process:

```
var ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

ipc.on('invokeAction', function(event, data){
    var result = processData(data);
    event.sender.send('actionReply', result);
});
```

Comment: When I use require in index.html the following error shows up.`
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` any idea why?

Comment: It seems you forgot to include the error. I don't currently have access to electron, but I think `require()` should be available in renderer process. Edit: OK it's now here.

Comment: @ant_1618 What version of Electron are you using? Also, on what OS?

Comment: using io.js v2.3.1 and Electron 0.29.1
On Linux 15.04

Comment: @ROAL: Yes indeed, it is possible to use `.once()`. Electron's IPC is a standard Node.js [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).
Also, `require('ipc')` has been depreciated, it's now `require('electron').ipcMain` and `require('electron').ipcRenderer`.

Comment: Is it possible to invoke ipc.once() before ipc.send() in index.html? Otherwise you might face a race condition.

Comment: @ant_1618 set nodeintegration in webpreferences when creating browserwindow

Answer (score 31):

You can use [webContents.executeJavaScript(code[, userGesture, callback])](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback) API to execute JavaScript code.

for example:

```
mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', ()=>{
    let code = `var authButton = document.getElementById("auth-button");
            authButton.addEventListener("click",function(){alert("clicked!");});`;
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(code);
});
```

Comment: Best to never allow any type of user input or external data when doing this.

Answer (score 10):

As stated in [this tutorial](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-architecture.md#main-and-renderer-processes):

> In Electron, we have several ways to communicate between the main process and renderer processes, such as ipcRenderer and ipcMain modules for sending messages, and the remote module for RPC style communication.

So you can follow the example in https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos. You should have a `js` file for each `html`. In that `js` file, you can use `require` anytime you want.

Code in [`renderer.js`](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos/blob/master/renderer-process/communication/async-msg.js):

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer

const asyncMsgBtn = document.getElementById('async-msg')

asyncMsgBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  ipc.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
})

ipc.on('asynchronous-reply', function (event, arg) {
  const message = `Asynchronous message reply: ${arg}`
  document.getElementById('async-reply').innerHTML = message
})
```

Code in [`ipc.html`](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos/blob/master/sections/communication/ipc.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require('./renderer-process/communication/sync-msg')
  require('./renderer-process/communication/async-msg')
  require('./renderer-process/communication/invisible-msg')
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case the window was created by invoking `window.open`
by default electron NodeIntegration is disabled, so you can't access the DOM of the other window.
changing the  property `nativeWindowOpen` to true fixed my issue.

```js
// in main.ts
async function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    // ....
    webPreferences: {
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
    }
  })
```

Now i can access the window.document element when i create the window using `window.open`