# Get DOM javascript variable from Node.JS in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Just like the title says, how can I get variable from DOM in main.js in electron.

Code:

value.js:

```
var x = document.getElementById('x');
```

main.js from ELECTRON:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')

require('./value.js') // include value.js
console.log(x.getValue());
```

The error says: document is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access DOM elements in electron?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for *interprocess communication*. While you can also use [remote](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/) for some things (It's basically a simplified wrapper of ipcMain and ipcRenderer), I didn't see a way to *set* a global variable (And I haven't used it myself). Instead, we can use [ipcMain](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md) and [ipcRenderer](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md) directly.

For example, you can have the following listeners in your main process:

```
let ipc = require('electron').ipcMain,
    test = 0;

ipc.on('setTest', (event,arg)=>{
  test = arg; // Beware of any possible user input!
  event.returnValue = test; // Required for sendSync or it hangs forever! You can send back anything here.
});

ipc.on('getTest', (event,arg)=>{
  event.returnValue = test;
});
```

And on the client side you can use something like:

```
let ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

ipc.sendSync('setTest', 1);
// and/or
ipc.sendSync('getTest');
```

**EDIT:** Since DOM elements are strange objects, you might have to use jQuery to [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) it before you can pass it around, or use another method of cloning to make it a JSON object (Or just send what you need in a simpler form). Alternatively, store things on the renderer and communicate when to do things via IPC.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're loading your JavaScript, you need to place your script **before** the HTML's `</body>` closing tag, or in a `window.onload` JavaScript function, as the document object does not automatically get created when you call `document.getElementById`.