# win.document.write ('content'); Cannot read property 'write' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to open a new window from electron via a JavaScript file, it works, and opens the new window but I can't write HTML/text to new file. I'm getting that error :

> Cannot read property 'write' of undefined

My simple code:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=300, height=200");
myWindow.document.write ('content');
```

Any advice or other way?

here's image from console:
[image]

Comment: It's working for me :/ , I just tried in the console

Comment: Despite the window opening for you, popups for your browser might still be disabled and causing the problem. Please check it.

Comment: I added image from console.. its electron window.
still not working for me,
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Weird things going on here... have you tried in another browser ?

Comment: this is the window that electron open for me:(

Comment: Okk so it has to be related to electron handling that event wrong... this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation for `window.open`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/window-open.md) states that, by default, it uses a different implementation of window.open, where it returns a BrowserWindowProxy instance. You can change it to use the native chrome one by passing `nativeWindowOpen: true` as an option when creating the parent BrowserWindow.