# accessing html element using id from a webview tag in electron.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I need to write javascript function to access a element using id from a webview in electron . Is it possible?
Can I write a code similer like 
document.getElementById("#idinsidewebviewtag");

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: You can find it here: [How to access DOM elements in electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron). But otherwise `getElementById` should work.