# Accessing webview DOM with Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to access the DOM inside the webview. I understand I need to use IPC, but with the following code which is in the same file, one accesses the parent and one accesses the webview.

**Preload.js** (using `preload` property of `webview`)

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.player')); // shows in webview
}, 1000);

ipcRenderer.on('ppause', () => {
  console.log(document); // shows in main window
});
```

**index.js**

```
window.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    globalShortcut.register('MediaPlayPause', () => {
        window.webContents.send('ppause');
    });
});
```

I want to be able to access the webview DOM (such as in the setInterval function), but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron

Comment: Nope, I think that's what I'm doing using ipc, unless I'm just confused.

Comment: Are you using webview in the main window like an iframe ? I read it is not recommended on the official web site. I may help with a child window. I could do it.

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out.

I needed to send it to the webcontents, and from there send it to the webview.

**preload**

```
ipcRenderer.on('ppause', () => {
    console.log(document); // can now manipulate webview DOM
});
```

**Browser**

```
const webview = document.getElementById('webview');
ipcRenderer.on('ppause', () => {
    webview.send('ppause');
});
```

**index.js**

```
globalShortcut.register('MediaPlayPause', () => {
    window.webContents.send('ppause');
});
```

All that was needed needed was an additional send to webview.