# document.getElementById(); returns null on an id that definitely exists

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know why document.getElementById("closebtn"); returns null? I have tried console.logging it, and i just get null. I am using node.js and Electron

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" />
    <script>
    console.log(document.getElementById("closebtn"));</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menubar">
        <button id="closebtn" onclick=""></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron

Comment: Move your script to just before `</body>`. The DOM needs to load before you can access it with the code.

Comment: Your script is loaded before your DOM here. Put it at the end or call your method after the DOM is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your script is running before the DOM is fully loaded. You can either place the script at the bottom of the body or wrap your code with [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). This will ensure that code placed inside will only be executed once the DOM is fully loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" />
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      console.log(document.getElementById("closebtn"));
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menubar">
        <button id="closebtn" onclick=""></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```