# Adding an click event listener to an element in an electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Error: document is not defined when starting up the electron app

I'm trying to make it so when someone clicks on a p element a function in my js file for running the electron stuff opens a new electron window but it keeps saying that document is not defined.

this is my index.html (main electron app file)

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>DTE</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Entery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; background-color: black">
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 39px;width: 100vw; height: 1px; background-color:white;"></div>
    <p id="commands" onclick="displayCommands()" style="position: absolute; bottom: -5px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);font-family: 'Roboto'; color: white;font-weight: 300;">Commands</p>
</body>
```

this is my js file for electron

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = electron;

let mainWindow;
let commandWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
    document.querySelector('#commands').addEventListener('click', () => {
        displayCommands();
    })
});

displayCommands = () => {
    commandWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 500,
        title: 'Avaliable Commands',

    });
    commandWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'commands.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
}
```

It pops up an error each time I run it saying this:

````
ReferenceError: document is not defined
   at App.<anonymous> (DIRECTORY_TO_ENTERY.JS:25:5)
   at App.emit (events.js:199:15)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access DOM (document) in your main process of electron, only in the renderer that it belongs to. Read this for more information [How to access DOM elements in electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into it and come back if I mess it up again