# How to read a button click event in electron js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron js application which loads [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) website in a windowless chromium browser. Am trying to capture the Submit button click event from the page like below

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Button Clicked'))
}
```

but its throwing an error even before page loads. Please suggest any alternate approach to capture the button click event.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: document is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access DOM elements in electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron)

Comment: No this for HTML created by us. In my scenario am launching a different website I don't have the control over the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

You have missplaced bracket, it should be like this:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Button Clicked')
});
```

Comment: It was jus a typing error but that didn't solve the problem