# Access web page DOM in electron BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I need to access the DOM of a web page that is loaded in my electron app. I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron) but not sure how to proceed in my case. At the moment this is the code I have in a dedicated file to load the browser window of electron.

```
'use strict'

/*
* Class WindowManager
*/

import { BrowserWindow } from "electron"
import { createProtocol } from "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib"
//import { autoUpdater } from 'electron-updater';
import path from 'path'

class WindowManager {
    constructor(){
        this.mainWin = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            autoHideMenuBar: true,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
                contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
                enableRemoteModule: false,
                preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
            }
        });
    }

    createWindow() {
        if(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
            // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
            //this.mainWin.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
            this.mainWin.loadURL('www.mysite.demo');
            if( !process.env.IS_TEST ) { 
                this.mainWin.webContents.openDevTools();
            }
        } else {
            createProtocol('app')
            // Load the index.html when not in development
            this.mainWin.loadURL('www.mysite.demo');
        }
        // Espando la finestra a tutto schermo
        this.mainWin.once('ready-to-show', () => {
            this.mainWin.maximize();
        })
        //if( this.mainWin.fullScreen ) {
            //autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
        //}
    }  

    getWindow() {
        return this.mainWin;
    }

}

export { WindowManager }
```

How I can access the DOM of the site correctly from the renderer process?