A Simple Electron App with a Button that calls a function reports to the console
/*
Hello everyone, I am working for the first time with electron. I have used JavaScript before. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong trying to get the button onclick event to call a simple function with a console.log operation in it. Any help would be appreciated because I am not sure where all the pieces go together.
Here's my code:
*/
// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");

let win = null;

const createWindow = () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
};

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

ipcMain.on("callMyFunction", (event, data) => { 
  // Prints inside the label called funcCallTxt
  funcCallTxt.innerHTML =  "This event: " + event + " and This data: " + data;

  // Writes to the console just to see what in the variables
  console.log("This event: " + event + " and This data: " + data) 
});



// renderer.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
    send: (channel, payload) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, payload),
});


// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script defer src="renderer.js"></script>
        <title>Call a Function</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>A Function Call</h1>
        <label for="funcCallTxt"></label>                
        <button type="button" onclick="callMyFunction()">Call My Function</button>
    </body>
</html>

I forgot to mention. There is absolutely no output from this code. Nothing happens, and nothing is printed to the console.

is anything at all being output to the "console"?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780726/how-to-access-dom-elements-in-electron This may help.

A few things to point out for guidance:

It is not possible to access the DOM from the main process, so doing funcCallTxt.innerHTML in main.js won't work.  This will need to be done in renderer.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld is a method that you need to use in a preload file, not renderer.  Methods you define in this preload file will then be available in renderer thru the global variable you define in preload.  In your example, this is global variable is electron.
To return a value to renderer from main, you can use the event.returnValue method of ipcMain event.

To put it all together, here is a basic example of how that would work, based on your example:
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script defer src="renderer.js"></script>
    <title>Call a Function</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A Function Call</h1>
    <label for="funcCallTxt"></label>
    <button type="button" onclick="callMyFunction()">Call My Function</button>
  </body>
</html>

main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')

let win

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')

  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.show()
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

// Listen for funcCallTxt call from preload.
// Then return a value and console.log when called.
ipcMain.on('funcCallTxt', (event, data) => {
  // "data" is what you passed to electron.send function in renderer
  // Value to be sent back to renderer thru preload:
  event.returnValue = data + ' = 2'

  // "event" here is the Electron.IpcMainEvent object
  console.log('This event: ' + event + ' and This data: ' + data)
})

preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

// Expose following to renderer under 'electron' global
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  // Send funcCallTxt directive to main with the data parameter from renderer
  send: (data) => ipcRenderer.sendSync('funcCallTxt', data)
})

renderer.js
function callMyFunction() {
  // Send the string "1 + 1" to main thru send function defined in preload and
  // assign the return value from main to the variable "fromMain"
  const str = '1 + 1'
  const fromMain = electron.send(str)

  document.querySelector('[for="funcCallTxt"]').innerHTML = fromMain
}


The code is not Windows specific. It works the same across most OS so nothing to rework. Please check your nodejs and dev configuration (ex. package.json). I tested on my end before posting and it worked fine.

Here's my package.json code:
{   "name": "schedule-generator",   "version": "1.0.0",   "main": "main.js",   "scripts": {     "start": "electron .",     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   },   "keywords": [],   "author": "",   "license": "ISC",   "description": "",   "dependencies": {     "electron": "^33.1.0"   } }
Please let me know where the issue may be.

What exactly doesn't work on your end?  Are you getting any errors?  I will list the steps I used for my example. 1. Make sure nodejs is installed. 2. Create an empty folder. 3. Open terminal and type npm init to create a node project in the empty folder. 4. Type npm i electron to install electron. 5. Add the start script and main.js to package.json (yours looks good)  6. Create the files, all in same folder: index.html, main.js, preload.js, renderer.js and copy the code I provided for each file.  7.  Run example by typing npm run start.

I've been debugging this code to better understand it. Currently, the error that I get is
"Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: electron is not defined at callMyFunction"renderer.js
function callMyFunction() {   // Send the string "1 + 1" to main thru send function defined in preload and   // assign the return value from main to the variable "fromMain"   const str = '1 + 1'
const fromMain = electron.send(str)
document.querySelector('[for="funcCallTxt"]').innerHTML = fromMain }
Could you please tell me what must I do to make this work?
